# ComboBox addRange

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

There is the possibility of insert range to combobox (windows store app)?
I need insert the range to combobox (array of characters).

NOTE: In form applications is:

```
combobox.Items.AddRange(object[]items);
```

I need some compromise for windows store comboBox.

Comment: Really not sure what you want. Can you provide more details of what you are after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you do it with XAML is you use the `ItemsSource` property of an `ItemsControl` (which `ComboBox` derives from) and the source may be any list. It should actually even work with a string (which is a list of characters), so you can do something like `comboBox.ItemsSource = "ABCDE";`